# Are Flash AMF calls blocking on AS3 client side?

Tags: actionscript-3, amf, amfphp

Are Flash AMF calls blocking on AS3 client side i.e. Do they block the client till the response is returned from the server side? What is the underlying transport protocol used for AMF, If it is HTTP then isnt HTTP supposed to be blocking in nature?

Answer (score 0):

AMF calls are asynchronous and result/error handling must be done via event listeners. Underlying protocol can be either HTTP or RTMP. Now, about HTTP being non blocking by nature - AS3 did not support threading until not so long ago (workers), so blocking and waiting for a HTTP response could be hidden by the runtime itself so that the interface won't freeze while waiting.